# How to handle the popup security alert in watir

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

After spending a full day trying to figure this out how to handle the security popup alert in Watir, I have basically hit the wall.

I'm trying to make a very simple script in that logs into this HTTPS site, which throws this popup alert that I can't get past.

To see this message, type: "security alert pop up" on this site "https://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=007267089725385613265:gmydx5gtw6u"

What I have tried is this:

1. Disabling this message alltogether in Firefox in the "about:config", but this is not possible as the warning will still pop up regardless.
2. I have tried to require the "WindowsHelper" and the "WindowsClicker" as found on this page : http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/wtr-general/2007-February/009181.html
   That documentation is rather old I see.
3. Also found an example that uses the ".use" on the messagebox and then click on it, but that did not help.

In both 2 and 3, the code I wrote could be wrong as I am not an expert in Watir.

The code I have now, looks like this:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'watir-webdriver'

SITE = "https://anypage.com"
BROWSER = Watir::Browser.start(SITE, :firefox)

Given /^I am on the login page for anypage$/ do
    BROWSER.goto(SITE)
end

When /^I successfully log in as a user$/ do

    BROWSER.text_field(:name => 'UserName').set 'USERNAME'
    BROWSER.text_field(:name => 'Password').set 'PASSWORD'
    BROWSER.button(:class => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block').click
    **MustHandlePopUpHere**
    BROWSER.do_more
end
```

Im using WatirWebdriver version 0.6.8 and Ruby version 1.9.3 if that is important.

Answer (score 3):

Watir has an API for dealing with alerts. You can confirm the alert using:

```
BROWSER.alert.ok
```

Here is a working example for the Watir search page:

```
require 'watir'

# Go to the page
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'https://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=007267089725385613265:gmydx5gtw6u'

# Input the search
browser.text_field(:id => 'q').set('security alert pop up')
browser.button(:value => 'Search').click

# Confirm the popoup
browser.alert.ok
```

You can read more about the alert API in:

- The [API Docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Alert) or
- The [Watir-Webdriver javascript dialogs page](http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/)